# ELF file versions

Tags: c, static-libraries, elf

I'm working on a clone of the `elfdump` command.

My program works fine when running `elfdump -ecps *file*` on all executables. However, when I run my program on a library file, say libc.so, it prints out an incorrect version number for all symbols in the .symtab section (specifically they are all zero). I've looked over the documentation tons of times, but I can't figure out why this is happening.

Can someone please provide some tips? Or possibly how to detect whether its a library or not so I could just hard-code a 0 in?

Comment: Your question isn't quite specific enough, we're unable to help above the specification. The specification is there and if you follow it things should work, if they don't try posting an exact example and it might get a good response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine if you're running against a shared library by checking to see if the e_type field is ET_DYN, I believe.  (man elf(5))

There is an [article](http://lists.debian.org/lsb-spec/1999/12/msg00017.html) by Ulrich Drepper that covers the glibc per-symbol versioning tricks in ELF.  Perhaps there is additional information there which you've not encountered before.  The man pages on linux don't appear to cover the per-symbol versioning information in the ELF docs.